# Join in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

How to Join with multiple conditions and use aggregate function in Rethink-db

```
r.table("yourtable").get(id).innerJoin(
r.table("secondtable"),function (up, upp) {
      return user_profile("mID")
}).map({  
     uId: r.row("left")("userId"),
     mId: r.row("left")("memberId"),
     pId: r.row("right")("projectId"),      
     nodeId: r.row("right")("nodeId"),
     pri: r.row("right")("priority")
 })
 .min("priority");
```

Comment: Any error msg ?

Answer (score 3):

```
    r.table("tblName1").get(id).innerJoin(
    r.table("tblName2"),
          function (tbl1, tbl2) {
               return tbl1("userId").eq(tbl2("userid"));
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below one where tblName1 Joins with tblName2. Having userId as mapping key. Note its a innerJoin.

```
r.table("tblName1").get(id).innerJoin(
   r.table("tblName2"),
   function (tbl1, tbl2) {
   return tbl1("userId").eq(tbl2("userid"));
   }).zip()
```

Also you can check a reference of all the sql to reql [here](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/sql-to-reql/javascript/).
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 .table("tblName1").innerJoin(
   r.table("tblName2"), function(tl, path){
     return tblName1("value").eq(path("value"));
   }
 ).map({nodeName:r.row("right")("value")   
   })
```